# how to create a template or document class for latex?

Tags: templates, documentclass-writing

I need to write a document class or template, as for an article, letter, etc.  Is there software for this?  How do I set it up so that anyone can use my class just like `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: How much experience do you have with LaTeX?  Writing a documentclass can be very intricate.  Is this an actual design project, or do you simply need a class to produce a particular result, like a letter?  If the latter, you should search on CTAN to see if an existing one will work.  Otherwise, could you give some detail on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I've edited your question for style; I hope you don't mind.  I hope I didn't remove anything that needed to be there!

Comment: thank you for your response. :) its ok i dont mind if you edited my question. Anyway, This is perhaps my first time to make a document class. I simply need to make a class in making an exam template. This template would include a customized names of the types questions. I read some tutorials on making one but i don't know where to make it? should be in windows? or Ubuntu? what software i should use for my project to function? hmmmm

Comment: @Kayla You say in your other comment that you don't have TeX Live.  Do you have MikTeX, then?  I ask because it sounds like you are a beginner, in which case you shouldn't try to write a documentclass.  Have you looked at the `exam` class?

Comment: i have miktex here.. and yes! im only a beginner. i looked one cls exam file in the web and i think it does not contain commands for question options in making the test questionnaire. i will be making those things in my own version of exam class.

Comment: @RyanReich:  Sir, if made my own class, and i want to use it, can it compile already by just declaring it in my .tex document? example \documentclass {kaylaexamclass} and so on..

Comment: @Kayla: If you write a class and call it `kaylaexamclass.cls`, and place it in the same directory as your .tex file, then `\documentclass{kaylaexamclass}` should work.

Comment: @RyanReich: what directory do u mean sir? u mean the folder where the program/application mikteX is installed?

Comment: @RyanReich: Sir!!! another question. hehe. have you tried making one document class in ubuntu linux?

Comment: @Kayla: No, the folder where your document is.  I have made a package in Ubuntu, but it's the same in any system.  You write the file mostly like any TeX file in whatever editor you would normally use.  There are differences where you *install* packages in Linux, but for you, it will be fine if you just put it with your document.

Comment: @RyanReich: so in short, i will just save my .tex file the same folder with the .cls file for my document to function. Am i right sir Ryan? :) Sir i think you're already an expert on this (LaTeX) so i assume you would give me suggestions on what will be the most helpful software app for creating my document class. if its ok. What do you think would be appropriate for me to use in making the document class.. is it mikTeX for windows?or should i make use TeXlive in ubuntu?

Comment: @RyanReich: Actually sir, i encountered unfamiliar errors while making my latex presentation in mikTeX. It says, that a particular thing is not installed yet but when i tried to install, it doesnt work. I compiled my files in ubuntu and boom! it does not return any errors. What do u think sir would be appropriate for me to use? i know making presentation in latex is using different class and what will i be doing is not for presentation.Its for exam. :) what should I do?

Comment: @Kayla: this is a different question and I think this comment discussion has gotten sort of long.  General advice about MikTeX: you can install packages using their package manager, if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: @RyanReich: Ofcourse I know that. What im just hoping was suggestion if you dont mind. Thank's a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 35):

Based on my comments, here is an answer.  To write a document class, all you need (really) is to create a file, say, `myclass.cls`, and put it in the same place as your document; then it can be loaded with `\documentclass{myclass}` and any macros defined in it will be available to the document.  The document `clsguide.pdf` that Higgs Boson linked describes all the various structured commands you *ought* to put in your class in order to give it a standardized appearance.  For example, you can declare its version and the version of LaTeX you need it to use, load other packages or classes in it, and accept options in the form `\documentclass[option,option2]{myclass}`.

As far as creating a class, no special software is needed.  A `.cls` file is exactly the same as any `.tex` file and you can write it in whatever text editor you normally write LaTeX documents in (perhaps you are using WinEdt, for example?).  There are a few questions around this site about what editors are recommended; [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) is a pretty big list.

If you are a beginner, you can look at existing classes for inspiration.  For example, since you are building an exam class, you might look at [exam.cls](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/exam.cls), which (though quite complex) is well-written and well-commented, so you might learn something about what a document class typically does.  Also see [their documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf).

I should say that if you are *really* a beginner, you should not be writing a class at all, and this example of a real documentclass will probably make no sense to you.  Start out by defining some new commands and environments in the default `article` class.  You can spin them off into an independent package later.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since this is a given project to us, i have no more options of changing it. I know it is quite complicated for me to create a new class rather than modifying an existing one as a beginner. But it is also a part of a beginner to learn what and how should it be done. That's what i am actually doing right now. Searching and Asking the veterans of the LaTeX world to have a more specified idea about the question i raised a while ago. Thank you! It really helped me. :P Good Day.

Answer (score 18):

If you have TeXLive installed, type `texdoc clsguide` as follows.

[image]

Pressing enter will open a manual for writing document class.

Or you can download it from CTAN, here [clsguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf).

Comment: `texdoc clsguide` works with MiKTeX as well. +1 for the screenshot, executing `texdoc` right from the search box is a nice tip. (Boo for IE and Chrome though)

Comment: @Kayla: our friend Stefan Kottwitz has a dedicated server for querying and browing TeX and LaTeX package information and general documentation, based on `texdoc`: http://texdoc.net/ You can type `clsguide` in the search box and get the documentation. `:)`

Comment: @doncherry: I removed IE from the screenshot but let Chrome stay intact.

Comment: The link in the post does not work, but I believe the document was moved and [this is the same file](https://web.archive.org/web/20200408201711/https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf).