# Is there a way make a custom default document style in LaTeX?

Tags: documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a template or document class for latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63358/how-to-create-a-template-or-document-class-for-latex)

Currently, whenever I create a new document, I add a reference in the header to

```
\input{header.tex}
```

where `header.tex` contains a whole bunch of package imports and default settings I like to use. Is there a way to put all of these settings in a custom document class, or something similar, so that when I create new `.tex` files, I can simply say, `\documentclass{custom_article}`, instead of having to copy the same file to a new folder every time and then reference it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create your own class, have a look at [Rolling your own Document Class](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/flynn/).

You can also find more detailed answers for these similar questions:

- [how to create a template or document class for latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63358/how-to-create-a-template-or-document-class-for-latex)
- [How to write a LaTeX class file for my thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51865/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-for-my-thesis)