# Creating a LaTeX Template from Data in Other Paths

Tags: input, include, paths

I want to make a template where I can modify one .tex file and have it pull various ''boilerplate'' (i.e., information that doesn't change) from a network. Firstly, I would have some .tex where the User will copy/paste into a new folder and then specify some stuff:

```
%% User Data
hello world!

%% Initialize document
\input{boilerplate/Preamble} %<----This folder would be located like C://User/etc,...
```

Then, I would have the Preamble pulled from within the Template folder, as well as, the remaining information:

```
%% Select class
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%% Packages
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label*=\arabic*.}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{breakurl} 
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
colorlinks=true,% hyperlinks will be coloured
citecolor=blue, % hyperlink text will be blue  
linkcolor=blue,% hyperlink text will be blue
linkbordercolor=blue,% hyperlink border will be blue
filecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
breaklinks = true,
hypertexnames=true,
}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

%% Begin Document
\begin{document}
\input{boilerplate/Introduction} % Need path
\input{boilerplate/DetailedEquipmentInformationandRequirements} % Need path
\input{boilerplate/ProductInformation} % Need path
\input{boilerplate/SupplierScopeofWork} % Need path
\appendix
\include{boilerplate/Appendices} % Need path
\end{document}
```

The folder structure I envision would be:

```
Template
-Boilerplate
--Introduction.tex
--DetailedEquipmentInformationandRequirements.tex
Project 1
-Compiler 1 .tex file
-Image Folder
Project 2
-Compiler 2 .tex file
-Image Folder
```

As you can see, I would need to call the Preamble and then call in various in data that are not in the same folder. Does anyone know an easy way to call in these information or perhaps a better management system?

Comment: TeX etc. is no CMS, unfortunately

Comment: I don't really understand the question. How can it pull in files from `boilerplate/` when `boilerplate/` doesn't exist?

Comment: @cfr I modified the original post; boilerplate is a folder with the .tex files.

Comment: how is this going to be a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a new local package or class, with auxiliary files.

First, create a directory, say `mytemplate`, either in your personal local texmf tree if you will be the only user, or in the site-wide local texmf tree, or distribute the final template as a zip-archive with instructions how people have to install it on their PC (in their personal or in the site-wide texmf-tree). In my case, under Linux, I'd create the `mytemplate` directory either as

```
$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/texmf/tex/latex/mytemplate
```

or for site-wide access as

```
$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/latex/mytemplate
```

Whatever you put into these folders will then be found without requiring an explicit path. Note that the site-wide local directory is usually indexed, so you have to rebuild the index after adding files to the directory. Under Linux, I call `texhash` as root (admin).

The common preamble and document settings become a style file `mytemplate.sty` or, if you need control over the document class loaded, [a class file `mytemplate.cls`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63358/110998). You then start the specific documents with `\documentclass{mytemplate}` (refers to `mytemplate.cls`) or with `\documentclass{anyclass}\usepackage{mytemplate}` (refers to `mytemplate.sty`).

Particular user data can be collected using commands that store it for later use or as parameters to commands that immediately process it. For the first approach, use LaTeX's `\author` command as a model:

```
\newcommand\@data{} % if it is ok that no data is provided
% or alternatively
\newcommand\@data{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\data given}} % gives a warning if the data is needed but has not provided
\newcommand\data[1]{\renewcommand\@data{#1}} % Store the argument under the name `\@data`
```

If the document contains `\data{42}`, then you can later access the value in your style or class file as `\@data`.

In the second approach the document calls a macro `\processdata{42}` and the data is immediately processed.

Regarding the text fragments, you can provide them as direct TeX code to be included. The document then has a line

```
\input{myintroduction}
```

If `myintroduction.tex` is located in the texmf-tree, it will be found without having to give the full path. Alternatively, your `mytemplate.cls` or `mytemplate.sty` can provide a command `\Introduction` (maybe with some parameters) that does some specific things and either contains the intro text verbatim or uses an `\input` statement itself.